# How to allow Stripe Checkout to proceed in Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, stripe-payments

When I attempt to open the Stripe Checkout inside my webview, I receive an error saying "there was a problem loading Checkout. If this persists, please try a different browser". When I run through the checkout process on Chrome Mobile outside of the Webview, the stripe checkout works flawlessly. It redirects to a webpage for the stripe checkout. Do I need to enable something in the application to allow for this to work in the WebView?

Code:

```
public class login extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_login_webview);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.icadeliveries.com/login");
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());


}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        TextView load = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LoadingText);
        load.setVisibility(view.GONE);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { //if back key is pressed
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: Maybe I am enabling popups incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Stripe doesn't support displaying Checkout in Webviews at the moment which is why you're getting this error. The best solution is to build your own payment [form](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js)

Comment: Okay thanks. That's a real bummer that Stripe has not added WebView checkout support yet